# showing the backdrop when opening the bootbox dialog from Modal screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I'm trying to display a bootbox dialog on top of another modal. The modal **behind** the bootbox dialog should be greyed out, thereby focusing attention on the bootbox dialog itself.

When the bootbox dialog is displayed as the only modal on the page, this functionality works fine, but not when you are trying to display the bootbox dialog on top of another modal (see screenshot).

Is there any way to do this?
[image]

Comment: Multiple bootstrap modals are not officially supported. This may help you, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755164/bootbox-dialog-inside-dialog/32794569#32794569

Comment: I was able to achieve this using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25981907/784789)